# Is there a way to instantiate a Class before an API call in Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

there's a heavy Class instantiation that I don't want to include every api call. So what I've thought to do is instantiate the class on server start.

So what I've come up with is something like this:

```
from package import Classobj
from flask import Flask

cobj = Classobj(arg1, arg2)
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/route', methods=['POST'])
def api_call():
    res = cobj.foo(arg1,arg2)

    return res
```

The class instantiation loads up a model, so it typically takes a few seconds just for that. The problem is, when I do it like this I get an error I can't trace.

Just this:

```
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("dense_1/Sigmoid:0", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

However, when I include the class instantiation on the api call, it works.

```
@app.route('/route', methods=['POST'])
def api_call():
    cobj = Classobj(arg1, arg2)
    res = cobj.foo(arg1,arg2)

    return res
```

Still pretty new to Python, would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: What are `arg1, arg2`? Are they coming from your imagination?

Comment: @Sraw, uh.. yeah they're placeholders.

Comment: We are going to need your real code.